# SOAPUI: run test-step with property from txt file, setting property to Property from txt

Tags: groovy, soapui

I use SOAPUI free version.

I have txt file like

```
1
2
3
```

I have test step, which should be run 1st time with 1, second with 2 etc...

Question: Can I somehow set that 1, then 2, then 3 as Property to property file?

And same question to xls, if text is not suitable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you've a SOAP test step called for example "myRequest" which contains something like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <yourRequest>
         <someValue>${#TestCase#myProperty}</someValue>
      </yourRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And you want to run this test step from groovy as many times than lines are in your file, using it content as a property in the request.

So in the groovy script you can use something like:

```
// define your file
def file = new File("C:/temp/yourFile.txt")

// for each line
file.eachLine { line ->
    // put the property for your request
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("myProperty",line)
    // execute your request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName( "myRequest")
    log.info "execute request for line: " + line
}
```

You can do the same, specifying the property at other level distinct of `TestCase` ( `TestSuite` level, `Project` level...) this is only a possible way to do so `:)`.

You can do it also from `.xls` however then maybe you need to add some libraries to deal with your `.xls` (like apache-poi) to `SOAPUI\bin` and change a bit of how groovy code to read it. I think that with `.txt` your goal is easy to achieve.

Hope this helps,